# Jquery click only executing once

Tags: jquery, click

my code is only working once.
When I click on the button, the code executes fine. But when I do the same **after it executed fine once**, it doesn't work, I don't even get the alert('clicked').

Anyone knows why?
Here is the code:

```
$('#eucontentpage #country-choice .item .lang-ico').click(function(){
    alert('clicked');
    $(this).parent().removeClass('item');
    var country = $(this).parent().attr("class");
    var language = $(this).html();
    var pathArray = window.location.pathname.split( '/' );
    var newPathname = "";
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      newPathname += pathArray[i];
      newPathname += "/";
    }
    var loadlink = newPathname + country + "/index_"+ language +".htm #nationalcontentpage";

    $.when(
        $('.lightbox').after('<div id="insertnationalcontent"></div>')
    ).done(function() {
        $("#insertnationalcontent").load(loadlink),
        $('#jb-window').hide(),
        $('#jb-window-content').hide(),
        $('#jb-overlay').hide(),
        $(this).parent().addClass('item'),
        $('#insertnationalcontent').fadeIn('slow'),
        $.history.load( '' )
    });

    return false;
});
```

Comment: I'm guessing this line is causing the jQuery selector not to match anymore: `$(this).parent().removeClass('item');`

Comment: I tried to leave it out of the click event, but it doesn't change a thing: $('#eucontentpage #country-choice .lang-ico').click(function(){

Comment: Please create a jsfiddle

Comment: @jens_vdp, can you also add your HTML in the question or better yet, create a JSfiddle :)

Comment: do $('#eucontentpage #country-choice).find('.lang-ico').click(...);

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this:

```
$('#eucontentpage #country-choice').on("click",".item .lang-ico",function(){ // this first part is different
    alert('clicked');
    $(this).parent().removeClass('item');
    var country = $(this).parent().attr("class");
    var language = $(this).html();
    var pathArray = window.location.pathname.split( '/' );
    var newPathname = "";
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      newPathname += pathArray[i];
      newPathname += "/";
    }
    var loadlink = newPathname + country + "/index_"+ language +".htm #nationalcontentpage";

    $.when(
        $('.lightbox').after('<div id="insertnationalcontent"></div>')
    ).done(function() {
        $("#insertnationalcontent").load(loadlink),
        $('#jb-window').hide(),
        $('#jb-window-content').hide(),
        $('#jb-overlay').hide(),
        $(this).parent().addClass('item'),
        $('#insertnationalcontent').fadeIn('slow'),
        $.history.load( '' )
    });

    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are removing the "item" class from the parent object. while using it in the object reference  "#eucontentpage #country-choice .item .lang-ico".

After removing the item class your referens does not match the any more.

try using just

```
$('.lang-ico').click(function(){...}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing  $(this).parent().removeClass('item');
So when this code executes it removes item class that's why your DOM selector is not matching.

Just comment below line your code will be executed multi time.
$(this).parent().removeClass('item');